# Returning integer from comparing two char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, char

Trying to figure out this particular funtion. I need it to scan passwords with punct[] to see if it contains one of the symbols, but I need it to bring back an integer if there is one. I tried n=strlen(password) but doesnt seem to work. This is what I have so far. I am also having trouble returning an integer for an if statement regarding an isalpha and isdigit which should pass passwords into it.

```
char password[17] = { '\0' };
char punct[] = { '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','?','_', '\0' };

    printf("Enter your test password: \n");
    fgets(password, 15, stdin);

for (int j = 0; n = (strnlen(password)); j < n; j++) {
        if (isalpha(password[j]) == true){
        int b = 1;
        printf(" Must consist of at least one number 0-9.\n");
    }
}
```

for is digit i have something like this in mind but I need it to run through the length of array

```
if(isdigit(passwords)){
return 1;}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _bring back an integer_? and _trouble returning an integer_ what integer??

Comment: I am trying to make a program where the user inputs something and it then checks to see if it has number, letters or the punctuations. If it is missing one of the items it will bring back an error. I wanted the program to create a 1 for each and then have a separate equation where if they were all 1's it would give a successful password creation screen. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

the best way it to use an array of 255 of unsigned char, `unsigned char flags[255]`.

then initialize the array once as so:

1= alpha

2= numeric

4= symbols

```
memset(flags,0,255*sizeof(short));
for(unsigned int i='A';i<='Z';i++) flags[i]=1; 
for(unsigned int i='a';i<='z';i++) flags[i]=1;
for(unsigned int i='0';i<='9';i++) flags[i]=2;

flags[(unsigned char)'!']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'@']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'#']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'$']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'%']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'^']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'&']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'*']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'?']=4;
flags[(unsigned char)'_']=4;
```

then run test:

```
short m_flags=0;
for(int i=0;i<strlen(password);i++)
    m_flags|=flags[password[i]];
```

result=:

```
   if(m_flags & 1) //alpha present
   if(m_flags & 2) //numerics present
   if(m_flags & 4) //symbols present
```